# Adding YearTotal to MDX query output

Tags: time-series, mdx

At present, I have the MDX query below as:

```
SELECT
{[Measures].AllMembers} ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Date].[Date].[Date]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model]
WHERE ([Date].[Year].&[FY17], [Entity].[Entity Hierarchy].[N].&[Total Company],[FactData].[Scenario].&[Actual])
```

that outputs:

[image]

What I would like add is a year total for that measure as:

[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the All member of the same hierarchy as `[Date].[Date].[Date]` in the set:

```
SELECT
  {[Measures].AllMembers} ON ROWS,
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
     ,[Date].[Date].[All]   //<<replace with whatever the All member of this hierarchy, in your cube, is called
    } ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model]
WHERE 
([Date].[Year].&[FY17]
, [Entity].[Entity Hierarchy].[N].&[Total Company]
,[FactData].[Scenario].&[Actual]);
```